# How do I fix the selected item in a drop down box

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have edit form where I get info from database

```
<select name="table">
<?php
                        //fetch all tables from database
  $user = $con->query("SELECT * FROM table") or die(mysql_error());
  while($row = $table->fetch_object()) { ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $row->tablename;?>">
  <?php echo $row->tablename; ?>
  </option> <?php }?> </select>

  <label for="time">Time :</label>
  <select name="time">

   <option value="twotothree">2PM-3PM</option>
   <option value="threetofour">3PM-4PM</option>
   <option value="fourtofive">4PM-5PM</option>
   <option value="fivetosix">5PM-6PM</option>

   </select>
```

The names of the tables from drop-down menu are different. Everytime I select a table and a time slot and save the data, the selection goes back to the first row of the menu. Eg I select table 3 and 4PM-5PM after saving it goes back to table 1 and 2PM-3PM. I need to be fixed on the last selection as I might use 4PM-5PM for table 4 also. Any idea? Thanks

Comment: Can you also show the code you use to save the selection when values goes back to "table 1 and 2PM-3PM."?

Comment: if ($_POST){

$tablename = trim(mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['fortables']));
$user = trim(mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['user']));
$time = trim(mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['time']));
 $result_user = $con->query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = '$tablename'"); 
 $rowuseradd = $result_user->fetch_object();
 $current = $rowuseradd->$time;
  //update tables
 $actual = $current.' '.$user;
 $con->query("UPDATE tables SET $time = '$actual' WHERE id = '$tablesname'");
 
  }

Comment: <label for="user">User :</label>
<select name="user">
        <?php
       //fetch all users from database
$user = $con->query("SELECT * FROM user") or die(mysql_error());
while($row = $user->fetch_object()) { ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $row->username; ?>"><?php echo $row->username; ?></option>
                              <?php }?>
                        </select>

Comment: Also I have user other that tables and time

Comment: So the thing is that your page is refreshed, and selected items in dropdown get lost?

Comment: I have the selected items saved in the database and displayed in a main table but the problem is in the drop-box menu as everytime I save data I have to select again table 3, 4PM-5PM and user xxxxxx. I need to keep the last saved selection as I have to use table 3, 4PM-5PM for yyyyyy as well

Comment: the items remain in the list, do not get lost but is a repeated operation, having 10 users to assign to the same table it can save time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add *selected* attribute when rendering your select list, depending on $_POST variable, when it's available. For example for you *table* select element:

```
<select name="table">
  <?php
  $user = $con->query("SELECT * FROM table") or die(mysql_error());
  while($row = $table->fetch_object()) { ?>
     <option value="<?php echo $row->tablename;?>" <?php if (isset($_POST['table']) && $_POST['table'] == $row->tablename) echo 'selected'; ?> >
     <?php echo $row->tablename; ?>
     </option> 
  <?php }?> 
</select>
```

In similar way you can do for *time* select element.

Comment: as per comment below